# How to link a Project Number to a Script dynamically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-forms

I'm creating forms on demand and i need to be able to set up the triggers. If i do it on the main AppsScript script that is handling the forms creation, i'll hit the 20 triggers max quota pretty soon. So i decided to add a dedicated script to every form (associating with parentID) so i won't hit the quota.

My problem is that when i try to add the triggers i'm getting permission denied since the scripts created for each form are using a default GCP project and it needs to be a standard GCP project due to OAuth.

I can add the project number manually, but that kind of defeats the idea of being able to generate google forms on demand.

I want to be able to link the script created with the standard GCP project that is already configured, but i just can't find anything on Google's documentation, i know its a long shot but i've decided to post here in hopes that someone that had the same problem managed to do so.

As requested on the comments below, the triggers that i'm using are:

onFormSubmit - get the response and send it to my endpoint in the backend server

onOpen - ensures that the editor hasn't removed anything default (this only works when an editor opens the form in edit mode)

---

This is the project number im referring to.
[image: GCP project number]

Thanks

Comment: What triggers are you crreating and what are they supposed to do.

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691) as was requested in the previous comment, please add more details about the triggers also mention if you are using a Google common account or a Google Workspace account.

Comment: It is not possible to update your script to use a standard GCP project. No existing method is available in [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts)

Comment: @Cooper, there are two triggers available for Forms in AppScript API. onFormSubmit (send the responses to my backend) and onOpen (checks when an editor opens the form to ensure that he doesn't mess up with the default things)

Comment: @Rubén Google Workspace account, and i've posted the triggers above, but i'll also edit the post.

Comment: You only need one onFormSubmit() for all of the forms in a project.  The onOpen  is not triggered when the user opens the form to respond but rather when the editor opens the form to modify it.  So what is it that you have to do for yourself or other editors that requires the onOpen.  I asked the question because you led us to believe that you need separate triggers for each form but I'm not convinced that is true.

Comment: @Cooper, im using the same script for all forms, but i can only have 20 instances of it. What i haven't tried and could work is creating a trigger and associating its id to all forms, i wonder if that would work. I know that the onOpen is exclusive for the edit page, what i do with it is ensure that the form editor hasn't messed with the default items that have been set when the form is first created, so if for example he removes an item, it creates it again.

Comment: If you use the onFormSubmit on the linked spreadsheet then you only need one trigger because e.range.getSheet() will tell you wish sheet is being written to and each sheet is attached to a different form.

Comment: I'm not using spreadsheets @Cooper

Comment: Well that's why you need more triggers then.  Where are you storing responses.?

Comment: The responses are being stored on my server

Comment: Hello, have you come up with a solution on this?

Comment: @AliTlekbai, it has been a while and I don't have access to that project anymore, but if I recall correctly we had to manually assign the project, at the time there was no way to dynamically assign the project ID. Sorry for not being able to help further